# Reactjs - Looping through state array to render JSX component - TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, typeerror

I am currently building a gallery view of cards that receive images from axios api call.

I make the call in a useffect hook and then pass the resultant object to useState to be stored.

I then access the contents of the stored object with urls.map, but I get the following error -->

*Uncaught TypeError: urls.map is not a function*

End goal is to be able to pass the urls from the array objects (path data.nfts.media[0].uri) to the NFTCard component with props. Tested props, they are working.

[This is the object that I am trying to filter through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih2c7.png)

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NFTCard from "./NFTCard";

function ViewNFT() {
  const api_key = "witheld for privacy";
  const address = "witheld for privacy";

  const [urls,setUrls] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://flow-testnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${api_key}/getNFTs/?owner=${address}&offset=0&limit=10`
      )
      .then(res=> {
        setUrls(...res.data.nfts);
        console.log(res.data.nfts);
      })
      .catch(err=> {
        console.log(err);
      })
  },[]);


  return (
    <>
    {urls.map((url,id)=>{
      return <div key={id}>
        <NFTCard pharaoh_url={url} />
      </div>
    })}
    
    
    </>
  );
}

export default ViewNFT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set function (`setUrls` in this case) returned by `useState` accepts a single parameter - either a value or a function. When you spread the array you get from the `api`, the only item that is stored is the first object, and since it's not an array it doesn't have the `Array.map()` method.

Remove the spread params from this line - `setUrls(...res.data.nfts);`

so it would store the entire array - `setUrls(res.data.nfts);`.

If you want to make a shallow copy of the array returned by the api (redundant unless used in multiple states), spread into a new array - `setUrls([...res.data.nfts]);`

Answer (score 0):

try this plz

```
  return (
    <>
    {urls && urls.length && urls.map((url,id)=>{
      return <div key={id}>
        <NFTCard pharaoh_url={url} />
      </div>
    })}
```